# The bar graphs not showing up in angular2+

Tags: angular, graph, charts

I have an application written in angular2+ and node.js. I want a page to display graphs and charts.
So i take input from drop-down and and that selection is sent to an http request and then retrieved into a variable like here -

```
    public barChartDataHighmark: any[] = [
     { data: [this.highmarkSuccessResult], label: 'Success' },
     { data: [this.highmarkErrorResult], label: 'Error' }
     ];
```

When i put hardcoded values ,the Bars in the  Bar graph appear,

Eg -

```
     public barChartDataHighmark: any[] = [

      { data: [10,11,12], label: 'Success' },
      { data: [5,6,7], label: 'Error' }
      ];
```

but when i set it as the output of my http request , the bars don't appear. How to resolve that.

[image: Unsolved Bar Graph]

**graphs.component.ts**

```
  viewHighmarkData(highmarkChoice) {


  this.highmarkInterfaceNames = ['Highmark', 'Highmark Issue Request', 
 'Highmark Commercial Auth', 'Highmark Comm Issue Request'];

  console.log("inside highmarkSuccess()");

   var url = config.url;
   var port = config.port;


  this.highmarkSuccessChoice = {
    'highmarkSuccess': highmarkChoice
    }

    this.http.post("http://" + url + ":" + port + 
    "/dashboard/highmarkSuccess/", this.highmarkSuccessChoice
  , { headers: new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 
    localStorage.getItem('Token') }) })
  .map(result => this.result = result.json(), )
  .subscribe((res: Response) => {
    // this.loading = false;
    this.records = res;
    console.log("xxxx view  Highmark  Success  result data ", 
     this.result)
    console.log("XXXXXXXXXXXX  view  Highmark  Success res data ", 
    res);

    this.highmarkSuccessResult = this.result.length;

      console.log("this.highmarkSuccessResult = ", 
      this.highmarkSuccessResult)
     });


     console.log("inside viewHighmarkError()");


   this.highmarkErrorChoice = {
   'highmarkError': highmarkChoice
     }

    this.http.post("http://" + url + ":" + port + 
   "/dashboard/highmarkError/", this.highmarkErrorChoice
  , { headers: new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 
   localStorage.getItem('Token') }) })
  .map(result => this.result = result.json(), )
  .subscribe((res: Response) => {
    // this.loading = false;
    this.records = res;
    console.log("xxxx view Highmark Error  result data ", this.result)
     console.log("XXXXXXXXXXXX  view Highmark Error  res data ", res);

       this.highmarkErrorResult = this.result.length;

       console.log("this.highmarkErrorResult = ", 
       this.highmarkErrorResult)
      });
    }
```

**component.html**

```
   // Highmark  BarChart

   public barChartOptionsHighmark: any = {
   scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
   responsive: true
   };
   public barChartLabelsHighmark: string[] = ['Success', 'Error'];
   public barChartTypeHighmark = 'bar';
   public barChartLegendHighmark = true;

   public barChartDataHighmark: any[] = [
     { data: [this.highmarkSuccessResult], label: 'Success' },
     { data: [this.highmarkErrorResult], label: 'Error' }
      ];
```

Comment: is this using chart.js?

Comment: Yes ....  import { Color } from 'ng2-charts';